Would it be halal for me to make a modification of a video game for money?
I'm new to programming and someone has offered me to make a macro for an RPG game which doesn't hurt other players gameplay, it just automates some part of the game to make it less boring for the player.
I was wondering if it'd be halal for me to make this since it's not affecting other players which is one of the main reasons I found cheating to be haram.
It would also be nice for me since I'm financially struggling but I would not do anything that would go against the Shariah.
It probably is haram because it's related to video games and its related to cheating in a way.
So an explained answer as to why it might be haram or not. As I said, the only reason I haven't turned down the request is because I am struggling financially. But, I won't continue with this offer if it turns out to be haram.
Might sound greedy and I'm sorry if it does but, if it's not haram can I sell something like this myself?
